# Get rows where lastLoginTimestamp is in last 7 days

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to get the rows from a table where `lastLoginTimestamp` is in last 7 days and I'm doing as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM representative WHERE DATE_SUB(lastLoginTimestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

`lastLoginTimestamp` is stored as a `VARCHAR` so this is where the problem is I though. How do get that rows in this case? Any help?

This are some of the values on that column to play with:

```
1427162434
1422557283
1395854997
```

**Update**

Based on the first answer I've changed my query to this:

```
SELECT
    *, from_unixtime(lastLoginTimestamp) AS lastLogin
FROM
    representative
WHERE
    DATE_SUB(
        from_unixtime(lastLoginTimestamp),
        INTERVAL 7 DAY
    )
```

But I'm getting the wrong values, for example I'm getting a row from this `lastLogin = 2015-03-23 21:30:34` which is wrong

Comment: Why, oh why, do you store timestamps as strings?

Comment: @ypercube wasn't me I'm just getting the works from others and yes I know this is insane and is wrong but I can't change at this moment, will do later in a new development

Comment: There are functions to convert to and from timestamp type.

Comment: [specify the format and convert it before the rest][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709744/isdate-equivalent-for-mysql

can you tell me what  '1422376080' means as date (wheat do you expect to see) so I can give you the right answer

Comment: @ypercube You mean execute a function on that column?

Comment: @ninjabber I don't know what the numbers stored are so I do not know how to convert them to the right value, I assume they are timestamp or so but not really sure

Comment: I can't designate the month??? Every single couple is bigger than 12

Comment: aaaaa, figured it out it's unix timestamp you get from your server logs

Comment: What exactky is the wanted condition? All the rows with a timestamp of 7 days ago and later?

Comment: @ypercube all the rows from the last 7 days not before that

Comment: If today is Tuesday April 7th, you want rows starting from last Wednesday April 1st, at `00:00:00`? Or from last Tuesday, March 31, at the same datetime an now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values seem to be Unix timestamps, stored as strings. You can use the special datetime functions that MySQL has for conversions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM representative 
WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(lastLoginTimestamp), INTERVAL 7 DAY) >= NOW() ;
```

but it won't be very good for efficiency. Much more efficient, if there is an index on the column, to do it the other way around:

<sup>(*we assume that the values in the columns are `CHAR(10)`. If some values have smaller length, you'll get erroneous results.)*</sup>

```
SELECT * 
FROM representative 
WHERE lastLoginTimestamp 
      >= CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS CHAR(10));
```

The above condition if you want all rows, starting from exactly 7 days ago, same time as now. If you want rows starting from 6 days ago at midnight, so previous 6 days + today (whatever that is, a few minutes or 23 hours, 59 mins):

```
SELECT * 
FROM representative 
WHERE lastLoginTimestamp 
      >= CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS CHAR(10));
```

Comment: +1 but I would recommend that the OP reads the links in the comments

Comment: @ninjabber I'm on it, thanks both, **ypercube** awesome it works prefectly

Comment: @ninjabber You can edit your answer and include any links you think are useful.

Comment: I like giving mysterious answers

Answer (score 1):

```
select from_unixtime("1427162434");
```

the rest you will figure out

but consider formatting the historical data and just change the type and test. Can't believe that the dates are pushed to the DB as chars.